How solid is the claim that Alfred Nobel founded the Nobel Prize specifically because of his invention of dynamite?
I've heard this claim my whole life.  It gets repeated a lot.
It's even listed at the American Chemical Society

Nobel created dynamite to help people in building and mining, but he and others also used dynamite to make bombs, canons, and rockets used in wars. Nobel wanted his inventions to help people. Instead, dynamite earned money by hurting people and damaging buildings during war. Before he died, Nobel decided to leave all the money that he earned from his inventions to make special awards for important inventions and actions. These awards are known as the five Nobel Prizes.

Thing is, dynamite isn't, to my knowledge anyway, a very widely used direct military explosive.  It might be used for demolition, but when one thinks of military explosives, you think of TNT, gunpowder, cordite, RDX and all the exotic stuff that has followed.
Not dynamite, which probably doesn't have the exact attributes desired to either propel projectiles or to be used in warheads.
Now, the wiki page on the Nobel Prize wiki does hint at some other possibilities, rather than specifically dynamite:

He was a chemist, engineer, and inventor. In 1894, Nobel purchased the Bofors iron and steel mill, which he made into a major armaments manufacturer. Nobel also invented ballistite. This invention was a precursor to many smokeless military explosives, especially the British smokeless powder cordite. As a consequence of his patent claims, Nobel was eventually involved in a patent infringement lawsuit over cordite. Nobel amassed a fortune during his lifetime, with most of his wealth coming from his 355 inventions, of which dynamite is the most famous.

Would it be more accurate to state that Nobel, who was a prolific military inventor and industrialist, founded the Prize, without necessarily attributing that to dynamite specifically?
Gun propellants - dynamite is not listed.
WW2 explosives - no dynamite either
dynamite

TNT is a second generation castable explosive adopted by the military, while dynamite, in contrast, has never been popular in warfare because it degenerates quickly under severe conditions and can be detonated by either fire or a wayward bullet.


@MCW  Is dynamite used as a gun propellant?  Is dynamite used as bomb/missile warheads?  It is not.  Do you have anything to back up your claim that it is?  "This reads like a pub argument" sounds like a mod who has an inflated opinion of themselves.

@MCW and please lay off editing people's title without a clear reason.  I took Mark's suggestion - it's not like I am averse to good suggestions.  But the meaning I intend to convey is that now in the title.

The German WP has a more extensive section on that question than the English articles. It says that, while the testament does not state reasons for the bequeath, there are only a few more inconclusive hints from conversations with others. It cites the (short) biography by Tore Frängsmyr as a source for that.

I'm almost certain that this legend was made up by people who had no idea dynamite was condemned by the militaries, as were all other nitroglycerine-based high explosives (in fact, by 1895 picric acid was the only military HE). Check this: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43461/is-there-any-record-of-the-premature-obituary-of-alfred-nobel

Without telling on a specific person, I have a ... erm ... very close family member, who has told this same story for years. I have indeed caught this person retelling urban legends before (but likely I've done so at some point in my life too).

@ccprog That would make for an alternative answer, but keep in mind it is itself prone to big claims: "with the exception of Ballistite none of Nobel's developments during his lifetime were used in the war."  Uh, Bofors as an arms vendor?  Even the Swedish wiki page is apparently merely copying other stuff like the unproven Merchant of Death article.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The fact that I was not able to read Frängsmyr's biography myself is the reason I abstained from posting this as an answer, only noting where one may be found.

Even if nowadays dynamite is not used as an explosive, and even if it was quickly overturned by other substances, it was a game changer at the time of its invention.
Dynamite was used in the military before ballistite was invented:

It was first used as a weapon during the Franco-Prussian War of 1870,
and between 1881 and 1885, Irish Republicans planted dynamite bombs at
government and military targets in Great Britain, injuring upwards of
80 people with more than two dozen devices.

And a French journal (describing the above):

It was these usages that led a French newspaper, under the mistaken
impression that Nobel had died in 1888 (it was actually his brother,
Ludwig) to publish an obituary with the headline, “The Merchant of
Death is Dead.”

Note: the information about the french newspaper may be an urban legend (thanks @ain92)
Nobel was both an inventor and a businessman.
As an inventor, all his inventions started from nitroglycerine (discovered by Italian chemist Ascanio Sobrero), and dynamite was the first viable commercial product - so you may say that everything started with dynamite, of which the other explosives are improvements.
As a businessman, he knew what marketing was, and a headline like that was surely free advertising.

Ah, that sounds more solid as an explanation than transposing it to its modern use.  But even then the Irish example reads more like a terrorist campaign, which is different in nature and for which I don't dispute dynamite's utility.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica It looks like dynamite itself was used in a very limited period for limited contexts. However, it was the founding product of Dynamit Nobel, Nobels company, who Nobel then went on to develop more militarily useful derivative products for within this period, like ballisite. Which Dynamit Nobel then manufactured.

The "Merchant of death" story only originated late in the 20th century, and it's most likely an urban legend https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43461/is-there-any-record-of-the-premature-obituary-of-alfred-nobel

Let's also keep in mind that this brief use - and how widespread would have been on 3 yr old tech? - was in 1870 and he died 26 years later.  However, I don't know if the public generally is aware that he did much more than invent dynamite, so I tend to figure they just latch on that and say "Hah! that's why he did it!"  I mean owning Bofors - these guys are still around, if under another corporate owner!

I can't do much more than link Wikipedia, but dynamite was apparently also popular as a warhead in pneumatic guns before more stable warheads were developed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamite_gun

Although it seems like a twist of logic to me, a contemporary account by a personal acquaintance of Alfred Nobel claims that Nobel considered his activities in furnishing war materials a contribution to the pacification of the world, to which his promotion of peace congresses late in his life and the establishment of a peace prize following his death provide a continuation. There is no specific mention of dynamite in this context.
From what I gather from contemporary publications, one of the products Nobel's company supplied for military use was a smokeless powder prepared from nitroglycerin and nitrocellulose, a precursor to cordite. In 1894 Nobel acquired the well-known Swedish arms manufacturer Bofors, which he still owned at the time of his death.
Henry de Mosenthal, "The Inventor of Dynamite", In The Nineteenth Century, No. 262, Dec. 1898, pp. 567-581 (my bolding):

ALFRED NOBEL, the inventor of dynamite, died on the 10th of
December 1896 at San Remo, and by his will his large fortune is
to be devoted to the encouragement of scientific research, and the
promotion of peace among nations. Having had the advantage of
personal acquaintance with him for a number of years, I have
undertaken to write this biographical sketch, for which his eldest nephew,
Mr. Emmanuel Nobel of St. Petersburg, as well as several of his friends,
have kindly supplied me with material.
[...]
With the
exception of legacies to relatives and friends, he left his entire estate
for public purposes, directing that the money be invested so as to
constitute a fund, the interest of which shall be applied to five equal
annual prizes to be awarded for the most important discovery or
improvement in chemistry, physics, physiology or medicine, for the work
in literature highest in the ideal sense, and to the one who shall have
acted most and best for the fraternity of nations, the suppression or
reduction of standing armies, and the constitution and propagation of
peace congresses.
[...]
The
intimate friends of Mr. Nobel have been invited to give information
which might throw light on his intentions, and two gentlemen, who
witnessed the will, have declared that he had told them that he was
a Socialist but one with moderate views; that in his opinion it was
not good for people to inherit large amounts, because it does not
stimulate them to work. He wanted his fortune to benefit those
who were working in the interest of humanity, and therefore he
wanted in the first instance those to profit by it who were occupied
with scientific research, because they could not, as a rule, reap much
material benefit from their labour. The fifth prize is to be explained
by the fact that towards the latter part of his life Nobel became
deeply interested in all that was done to promote peace by congresses
and societies. He always considered that by improving war material,
and thus increasing the dangers of war, he was contributing his share
towards the pacification of the world.


Nobel himself worked on improving [high-]explosives 'insensitivity'. 'Pure' dynamite was indeed only one of his inventions, albeit perhaps his most successful one, commercially. He actually reused the term for various variations, but also coined new terms...

In 1867 Swedish entrepreneurs began substituting ammonium nitrate in part for nitroglycerin. Nobel himself created "extra dynamites" containing 20-60% ammonium nitrate in a gelatin form. For about the next two decades, researchers worked at developing nongelatinous mixtures with ammonium nitrate, but ammonium nitrate is too hygroscopic. [...]
In 1875 Alfred Nobel sought to develop a
cohesive energetic material that would detonate underwater. [...] He found that he could add 7-8% pure
gun-cotton (nitrocellulose) to nitroglycerin He called the doped mixtures "gelatin dynamites". Gelatin dynamites had
high water resistance and greater blasting
power than straight dynamites, resulting
from the higher density of the material and
also its plasticity (which allowed complete
packing of a borehole). Water gels remain
extremely popular even today, composing
more than 10% of all industrial explosives
used in the United States.
[...] In 1884 French chemist Paul Vieille partially dissolved nitrocellulose in a mixture of
ether and alcohol until it turned into a gelatinous mass, which he rolled into sheets.
After drying, these sheets could be cut into
flakes. After the solvent evaporated, the
hard and dense material remaining was
similar to hom, and could be used as a propellant for all kinds of guns. This was the
first example of "smokeless powder".
Nobel introduced his own smokeless
powder, "ballistite" in 1887, by mixing 40%
of a more soluble type of nitrocellulose
(which had a lower nitrogen content) with
60% nitroglycerin. This type of smokeless
powder continued to be popular for 75
years. The British ignored Nobel's patent
on the material and developed their own
similar products under the general name
of "cordite".

So, if you take his idea to mix nitroglycerin with various other substances to make it less sensitive his dynamites (even if they were not all called that) were more than one thing. And some surely had more military applications than others. Nobel himself doesn't appear to have contributed anything to (dedicated) shell explosives like TNT.
There were a few early guns that fired dynamite-based shells, but these were (soon) replaced by safer alternatives. The US even built a cruiser around the concept, which was used to bombard Cuba. The downside of using dynamite in the shell was apparently that it could not withstand being fired by combustible gun propellants, so compressed air was used instead, which lowered muzzle velocity and range.

The explosive used in the shells themselves was actually a "desensitized blasting gelatin" composed of nitrocellulose and nitroglycerin. It was less sensitive to shock than regular dynamite, but still sensitive enough that compressed air, rather than powder, had to be utilized as the propellant. Shells containing 550 pounds (250 kg) of explosive had a maximum range of 1 mile (1.6 km), but range could be extended to 4,000 yards (3.7 km) by reducing projectile weight to 200 pounds (91 kg). Maximum muzzle velocity was 800 feet (240 meters) per second.

I hope this clarification is useful, although by itself it doesn't answer the Q how much all of that [military aspect] affected his decision to set up his posthumous prize.
FWTW, the same piece ends with

Ironically, when Alfred Nobel first created dynamite in 1866, he had believed
that the proliferation of military explosives
would make all warfare obsolete because
the death and destruction would be too
horrible to risk.

His pacifism has been a bit debated though:

In the literature on Alfred Nobel, there exist different interpretations of his ideas and involvement in the peace question. In some works it is claimed that the interest in peace accompanied Alfred Nobel since his youth, in others that he did not come to reflect over questions of mankind’s fate until quite late.
As a young man, Alfred was present when his father, Immanuel Nobel, constructed on the Russian Czar’s account the first truly usable sea mines which came into use in mid-century during the Crimean War. Alfred’s own great invention, dynamite, had not been developed with the idea of using it in war. [...]
Of more direct military importance was another of Nobel’s inventions, which he developed in the 1880s. Nobel originally offered to the French government, ballistite or “smokeless powder”, but due to certain complications, it came to be sold to Italy instead. Nobel later declared that it was the problem’s theoretical aspects which made him tackle the task.
[...] Alfred Nobel’s direct involvement in the war materiel sector did not come about until during the later stages of his life. It was also at this time that his interest in the question of peace came into practical expression. His thoughts on war and peace were set out in many years of correspondence with the Austrian peace partisan and authoress of the famous anti-war novel “Lay down Your Arms”, Bertha von Suttner.
According to the Austrian countess Bertha von Suttner, Alfred Nobel, as early as their first meeting in Paris in 1876, had expressed his wish to produce material or a machine which would have such a devastating effect that war from then on, would be impossible. The point about deterrence later appeared among Nobel’s ideas. In 1891, he commented on his dynamite factories by saying to the countess: “Perhaps my factories will put an end to war sooner than your congresses: on the day that two army corps can mutually annihilate each other in a second, all civilised nations will surely recoil with horror and disband their troops.” Nobel did not live long enough to experience the First World War and to see how wrong his conception was.
One could of course say that Nobel’s view on the war deterring effect of weapons and explosives — what would be later called the balance of terror — was a comfortable way for him to defend his own activity. [...]

So, he did seem to think (or at least formulated) a view that the armaments industry that he contributed to a sort of mutually assured destruction situation, where the prospect of high casualties would lead to no more wars.
How much of that relates to the prize transpires in another quote:

Even if Alfred Nobel for a long time maintained a certain cool distance to the international peace association’s methods, his interest in a donation to the promotion of world peace was influenced by Bertha von Suttner. In his last will, signed on November 27, 1895, we find the well-known prize formulation “to the person who shall have done the most or the best work for fraternity between nations, for the abolition or reduction of standing armies and for the holding and promotion of peace congresses.”
[...] Evidently, Alfred Nobel did not consider his involvement in the war materials industry and in the work for world peace as incompatible elements. Rather he gave expression to the prevalent 19th century understanding which maintained, that the scientist was not responsible for how his findings were used. Each scholarly discovery is neutral in itself, but can be used both for good and bad objectives. And when it was applied to weapons, Nobel held firm to his old opinion that this had a deterrent effect above all.

So, it's probably rather incorrect to think he had guilt about his inventions, and that that led to the prize. He seems to have thought that more effective weapons lessened the likelihood of conflict.
The same take is in this piece based on a 2021 biography of him. That one also discusses his acquisition of cannon-maker Bofors, a couple of years before he died, and the Europe-wide legacy of his other armament-related firms, as well as his late life interest in "rockets for military use".

BTW, there may be some level of cofusion with Sobrero, who discovered nitroglycerin, which Nobel later made somewhat safer to use (as dynamite). Sobrero did express some remorse about his discovery:

Sobrero, who had been badly injured in a nitroglycerin explosion during his work, was at first “mortified” to hear about Nobel’s work, according to the Nobel Prize website. "When I think of all the victims killed during nitroglycerin explosions, and the terrible havoc that has been wreaked, which in all probability will continue to occur in the future, I am almost ashamed to admit to be its discoverer,” he said of nitroglycerin after dynamite had become a relatively common substance. But after dynamite made the Nobel family extraordinarily rich, some accounts say that he was resentful of their riches and didn’t feel he was given enough credit for his work, writes [Nobel's biographer] Fant.

